# How to use path parameter in GenericViewSet, Mixin CBS?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new in DRF, Django.

I want to make get API with path parameter which name is period.
(ex. localhost:8000/api/ranks/{period})

views.py

```
class RankingView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  GenericViewSet):

    queryset = Record.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecordSerializer

    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=False, url_path='<str:period>', url_name='<str: period>')
    def get_rank(self, request, period):
        #logic
        return
```

urls.py

```
router.register(r'api/ranks', RankingView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

But, its not working. It might be easy to solve but I couldn't find answer.

Comment: You are not providing the actual error. But besides that `url_name` should be a string like `"get-rank"` and the URL paths should end with a `/`.

Answer (score 1):

try to add specific path like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', include(router.urls)),
path('api/ranks/<str:period>', views.RankingView.as_view({
'get': 'get_rank'
})),
]
```

Comment: thank you for your idea! and sorry for late comment.

should I seperate view?? I used genericViewSet with mixins for good managing about router, url.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with python regular expression.

class RankingView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
GenericViewSet):

```
queryset = Record.objects.all()
serializer_class = RecordSerializer

@action(methods=['GET'], detail=False, url_path='(?P<period>\w+)')
def get_rank(self, request, period):
    #logic
    return
```

It makes easy to manage urls, and also can easily use path parameter with mixins, viewSet.